# MonoTouch - xib.designer.cs files losing fully qualified paths for UIKit Objects

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Any MonoTouch Solution I create has this issue, If I make any change to the project structure (Add a folder, modify a .xib, add a file etc) my project will not build anymore as all of the UIKit objects no longer are full qualified:

From this: private MonoTouch.UIKit.UIWindow

To: private UIWindow

does anybody have any advice?

Comment: Could you share the project file with my team so we can look at it?   What versions of XCode, MonoDevelop and MonoTouch are you on?

Comment: Sure! Where do you wish me to send it? XCode V4.0 Build 4A304a, MonoDevelop 2.4.2, MonoTouch 4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by installing Mono 2.10.1, which is now in the MonoDevelop updater.