# DoNotChange was not found when adding new files

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I attempt to add a new file to the solution -- even a general C# empty class, I get an error:
The requested value 'DoNotChange' was not found. See [screenshot](http://i56.tinypic.com/vryb82.jpg).

This just started happening yesterday. I installed the monotouch-4.0.0.dmg, but have since rolled back to 3.2.6, but the problem remains.

I think there may be a fairly widespread issue, as [this new StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582622/monotouch-xib-designer-cs-files-losing-fully-qualified-paths-for-uikit-objects) seems eerily similar.

Anyone have any ideas on how to recover?

Environment:

- MonoTouch Professional 3.2.6 (4.0.0)
- MonoDevelop 2.4.2 release 20402004
- OSX 10.6.7

**UPDATE:** On a whim I tried to create a new empty .cs file outside of MT, and then add it to the project -- that worked, so at least there is a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your formatting policy options are triggering a bug in the code formatter. Try resetting it by removing the file ~/.config/MonoDevelop/DefaultPolicies.xml

Comment: I downloaded and installed the 2.6 beta version of MonoDevelop. Before running, I removed the DefaultPolicies.xml file. 

Not sure if this suggestion, or the reinstallation fixed the problem, but it's gone now. 

Thank you much!